# Programmatically position UILabels added dynamically inside UIView with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, autolayout, visual-format-language

I have an array of items to be display inside of my `UITableViewCell`. Each of these items will be dynamically displayed using `UILabel`. I use autolayout to setup the views layout.

Here's how I layout my `tableViewCell`:

```
+------------------------------------------------+
| [cellView]                                     |
| +---------------------------------------------+|
| |[otherView] <- fixed height                  ||
| | +------------------------------------------+||
| | |[UILabel]                                 |||
| | +------------------------------------------+||
| +---------------------------------------------+|
| +---------------------------------------------+|
| |[itemView]                                   ||
| | +---------------------------+ +------------+||
| | |[itemLabel]                |-|[priceLabel]|||
| | +---------------------------+ +------------+||
| | +---------------------------+ +------------+||
| | |[itemLabel]                |-|[priceLabel]|||
| | +---------------------------+ +------------+||                                            
| |                                             ||
| |     --Add the next UILabels dynamically--   ||
| +---------------------------------------------+|
+------------------------------------------------+
```

For clarity

- `otherView`: have 2 `UILabel` inside of it. Fixed height.
- `itemView`: have unknown number of `itemLabel` & `priceLabel` inside. Will resize height based on the number of `items`.
- Each of the views constraints is set using storyboard except for `itemLabel` & `priceLabel`.

---

Inside my `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, I set the `itemLabel` & `priceLabel` constraints using `constraintsWithVisualFormat:`

```
for (NSDictionary *item in items) {
    UILabel *itemLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    itemLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    itemLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    itemLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    itemLabel.text = [item valueForKey:@"item_name"];
    [cell.itemView addSubview:itemLabel];
    
    UILabel *priceLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    priceLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    priceLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
    priceLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentRight;
    priceLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    priceLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RM %@", [item valueForKey:@"price"]];
    [cell.itemView addSubview:priceLabel];
    
    NSDictionary *viewsDictionary = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(cell.itemView, itemLabel, priceLabel);
    [cell.itemView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[itemLabel]-5-[priceLabel(70)]|"
                                                                         options:0
                                                                         metrics:nil
                                                                           views:viewsDictionary]];
    [cell.itemView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[itemLabel]|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDictionary]];
    [cell.itemView addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|[priceLabel]|"
                                                                          options:0
                                                                          metrics:nil
                                                                            views:viewsDictionary]];


}
```

The end result is as below. The only problem is that the `itemLabel` and `priceLabel` created are overlapping with each others instead of aligning nicely from top to bottom.

**Results:**

[image: End results]

**View debug:**

[image: View debug]

How do I set the constraints properly so that the `itemLabel` & `priceLabel` will align nicely from top to bottom and the `itemView` will resize based on the number of items inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have insufficient constraints. The problem is that you are not setting constraints between, let's say, one `itemLabel` and the *previous* `itemLabel`. As you loop, you need to keep track of the previous item label so you can space this one down from it.

To put it another way: the technique you are looking for is that there are three cases:

- The *first* label. It is pinned to whatever is above it (possibly the top of the superview).
- All other item labels except the last. Each is pinned to the previous label.
- The *last* label. It is pinned to the previous label *and to the bottom*, thus giving the cell its height.

By an incredible coincidence, I actually have on hand some code that illustrates this principle; the situation is obviously not 100% identical to yours, but the principle is exactly the sort of thing you want to be following here:

```
UILabel* previousLab = nil;
for (int i=0; i<30; i++) {
    UILabel* lab = [UILabel new];
    // lab.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    lab.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    lab.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"This is label %d", i+1];
    [sv addSubview:lab];
    [sv addConstraints:
     [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|-(10)-[lab]"
                                             options:0 metrics:nil
                                               views:@{@"lab":lab}]];
    if (!previousLab) { // first one, pin to top
        [sv addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-(10)-[lab]"
                                                 options:0 metrics:nil
                                                   views:@{@"lab":lab}]];
    } else { // all others, pin to previous
        [sv addConstraints:
         [NSLayoutConstraint
          constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[prev]-(10)-[lab]"
          options:0 metrics:nil
          views:@{@"lab":lab, @"prev":previousLab}]];
    }
    previousLab = lab;
}

// last one, pin to bottom, this dictates content size height
[sv addConstraints:
 [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[lab]-(10)-|"
                                         options:0 metrics:nil
                                           views:@{@"lab":previousLab}]];
```

Comment: By the way, I am not 100% convinced that this is a good use of a table view. But that's another issue! :)

Comment: Alright, I've tried the three cases and it works. Now i only need to resize the superview and cell. Thanks @matt. :)

Comment: @faizmokhtar instead of putting the multiple label on top of each other inside a cell, wouldn't it be better if each label is inside their own cell? Each order can be a section (the order number printed as the section header), therefore your tableview won't need to load the whole data, and you have bigger flexibility on customise your table later on

Comment: @usergio2 Yes, this is what I meant in my earlier comment when I said that this does not sound like a good use of a table view. However, the problem as stated does deserve consideration, even if it is not the right way for the OP to create the actual interface.

Comment: @usergio2 Yeah, I end up with your suggestion instead. Thanks :)